# Extend \mapsto to exhaust space between the column elements of a given table

Tags: tables, math-mode, spacing, vertical-alignment

I have the following issue: I want to express the composition of functions via the image of certain elements. The following table is an example:

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
        & $A(e_0,\dots,\widehat{e_i},\dots,e_p)$& &$A(v_0,\dots,v_p)$&\\
        $e_0$ & $\longmapsto$ & $e_0$ & $\longmapsto$ & $v_0$\\
        $\dots$ & & $\dots$ & & $\dots$\\
        $e_{i-1}$ & $\longmapsto$ & $e_{i-1}$ & $\longmapsto$ & $v_{i-1}$\\
        $e_i$ & $\longmapsto$ & $e_{i+1}$ & $\longmapsto$ & $v_{i+1}$\\
        $\dots$ & & $\dots$ & & $\dots$\\
        $e_{p-1}$ & $\longmapsto$ & $e_p$ & $\longmapsto$ & $v_p$\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

However, as you may realize, the name of the functions is too wide for \mapsto to make this a good-looking table. How can I extend the length of \mapsto so it can match the length of the widest element of its column? Is this even possible? How could I improve this presentation, if possible?

Thanks in advance for your time.

P.S. This is my first post in this site, and this is the first time I am ever typing an essay in LaTeX, so I would really appreciate a clear, full answer, if possible.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define `\mapstofill` in a similar way as `\rightarrowfill`.

I used `array` in order to reduce the number of `$` symbols; this has the consequence that `\mapstofill` has to be between `$` symbols so as to close math mode and to reopen it at the end.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\mapstofill{%
  $\m@th
  {\mapstochar}%
  \smash-\mkern-7mu
  \cleaders\hbox{$\mkern-2mu\smash-\mkern-2mu$}\hfill
  \mkern-7mu
  \mathord\rightarrow
  $%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
        & A(e_0,\dots,\widehat{e_i},\dots,e_p) &         & A(v_0,\dots,v_p)           \\
e_0     & $\mapstofill$                        & e_0     & $\mapstofill$    & v_0     \\
\vdots  & \vdots                               &         & \vdots                     \\
e_{i-1} & $\mapstofill$                        & e_{i-1} & $\mapstofill$    & v_{i-1} \\
e_i     & $\mapstofill$                        & e_{i+1} & $\mapstofill$    & v_{i+1} \\
\vdots  & \vdots                               &         & \vdots                     \\
e_{p-1} & $\mapstofill$                        & e_p     & $\mapstofill$    & v_p     \\
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very very creative :-)

Answer (score 5):

`\mapsto` can be made into an extensible arrow
in the same way that the `\x...arrow`s are extended
by `amsmath`, also drawing on the definition of
`\mapsto` in `plain.tex`.

Here is an example, comparing it with `\longmapsto` as
defined in `plain.tex` and provided natively by any
LaTeX setup.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xmapsto}[2][]{\mapstochar \ext@arrow 0359\rightarrowfill@{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
some text
\[
 x \overset{a very long modifier}{\longmapsto} y
\]
more text
\[
 x \xmapsto{a very long modifier} y
\]
more text

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

To use it in a table as requested, the modifier can be replaced by an `\hspace*` and the whole expression buried in a `\mathclap` (defined in `mathtools`).  This does require an explicit choice of the length but maybe someone else can adapt this to be more automatic.

**Update:** 
As reminded by @Schrödinger's cat, `\xmapsto` already exists in `mathtools`, so it doesn't need to be redefined.  (But I'll leave the definition since seeing how it's constructed might be found interesting by someone who likes to explore details.)

Comment: I have never seen the command \mathclap. How does it work in this case?

Comment: @Akerbeltz -- `\mathclap` is one of a family of `\*lap`s.  These are defined to make the width of their argument be zero, so it can be positioned to overlap something else.  `\rlap` overlaps to the right; "l" to the left; "c" centers on the current position.  "math" indicates that the construct is to be used in math mode.  In the present case, `\mathclap` would center the argument horizontally at the current position, placing half to the left and half to the right.

Comment: `mathtools` has this built in, so you may want to add `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
some text
\[
 x \xmapsto{\text{a very long modifier}} y
\]
more text
\end{document}` as an alternative.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat -- Thanks for the reminder; just shows how quickly one forgets this sort of stuff after going inactive.

Comment: I know, `$\text{knowledge}\xmapsto{\text{honey liquor}}\text{ignorance}$` or `$\text{knowledge}\xmapsto[\text{liquor}]{\text{honey}}\text{ignorance}$`. ;-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat -- Indeed, although my libation of choice these days is nigori sake.  Just don't forget to shake thoroughly before pouring.